# Reading HTML file into textbox translates apostrophes and bullets into?

Tags: c#, encoding, streamreader

I am using a StreamReader (in C#) to read contents of an HTML file into a textbox.  No matter which encoding I use as an uption, all of the apostrophes and bullets get changed into question marks.

Is there another way to read an HTML file that will preserve these characters?

Thanks!
Jerry

Here is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); 
     if (result == DialogResult.Cancel) 
         return; 

     StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName); 

     txtMessage.Text = sr.ReadToEnd(); 
     sr.Close(); 
 }
```

I have also used the StreamReader with the Encoding parameter (tried every one).  The only thing it seems to do is interpret the question marks are regular or reversed (black diamond with white question mark).

If it makes any difference, the files are created in Word by another department and then exported to Filtered HTML.

One last thing:  If I open the HTML file in something like Notepad and copy/paste the text into the textbox, then everything looks exactly as it should.

The changes only occur if I try to pull the file in via a reader.

Comment: It's because of the typo on line 31.  No, really... paste the code or we can't help you debug.

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.Cancel) return;

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            txtMessage.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }

Comment: Sorry, that formatted horribly.

Comment: Edit your question and add it there instead of adding comments.

Comment: You've tried every single encoding? I find it hard to believe... Either way the problem is clearly in encoding you use to open StreamReader with... which in your example you don't.

Comment: The encoding isn't in the example because the last test was to try the default.  It really isn't that hard to test with the six encodings offered.

Answer (score 0):

I would try it with `new StreamReader(..., Encoding.UTF8);` or `new StreamReader(..., Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));` and if that doesn't work, then I'd go after the person who created the file and stuff needles under their fingernails until they confess what encoding they used to create it.

Comment: Already tried.  I am going to recreate the HTML file without Word and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Funny, I tried the GetEncoding that you recommended and it changed the apostrophes to blank spaces.  However, the bullets look perfect.

Comment: I got it!  Had to use your encoding AND change Word's default coding for webpages from Wester European(Windows) to Wester European(ISO).  Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: well if that much is known then all you had to do is change your code to `new StreamReader(..., Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))`